# C++ assign a logical operator function to a variable

Tags: c++, function, variables, logical-operators

I am trying to assign a logical operator function to a variable but am unable to get it to work. I am using:

```
function<bool(double,double)> opFunct = less<bool>();
double highorlow = pOut.high;
if(pCheck){
     opFunct = greater<bool>();
     highorlow = pOut.low;
}
if(opFunct(highorlow,pStay.middle){
     //never gets done
}
```

The problem with this code is no matter what the highorlow,pStay.middle doubles are, it returns false.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: That looks overengineered and has syntax issues.`std::function` is not a lightweight object. Why not just use a plain pair of `if`s?

Comment: I was pulling code from my python project and trying to match. will optimize later. Just more of a want to know how to for later:)

Comment: `less<bool>()` compares two bools for less-than. You want `less<double>()` and similarly `greater<double>()`. The erroneous behavior is because the doubles are being converted to bools (0 is false, anything else is true). Since your numbers are probably both nonzero, you are comparing to see if true is less than true.

Answer (score 2):

**Short version**:

`less<bool>` compares `bool`s. Use `less<double>` to compare `double`s (also in `greater<>`).

**Long version**:

This is an interesting question. Specifically, how come the following line compiles?

```
function<bool(double, double)> opFunct = less<bool>();
```

After all [`std::less<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)`:: operator()` looks like `bool(bool, bool)`, why does it match `bool(double, double)`?

Well that's because the check that [`std::function`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) performs is simply whether `less<bool>()` can be invoked as `bool(double, double)`, and yes it can! `double` is implicitly-convertible to `bool`, `0.0` becomes `false` and  any other value `true`.

That obviously won't produce the expected result because e.g. `opFunct(1.0, 2.0)` will invoke `less(true, true)` which will return `false`.

The fix is to change `bool` to `double`

```
function<bool(double, double)> opFunct = less<double>();
```

And also here

```
    opFunct = greater<double>();
```

But wait, `std::function` overhead aside<sup>1</sup>, depending on how the rest of your code looks like, the fragment shown can potentially be simplified to just:

```
if (pCheck ? pStay.middle < pOut.low : pOut.high < pStay.middle) {
    // . . .
}
```

Or maybe even

```
if (pStay.middle < pOut.low || pOut.high < pStay.middle) {
    // both checks at once . . .
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>`std::function` comes at a cost of some 48-96 bytes of memory and an extra indirection or two. Compare the generated code for [version with std::function](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TxaHM-) vs. [version without std::function](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pn7U-z).</sub>

Comment: No no warnings.. why would it? `std::function` constructor behaves as specified: *...this constructor does not participate in overload resolution unless f is Callable for argument types Args... and return type R.*

Comment: Just wanted to verify my suspicion. No warning for totally broken code. There are even reasons for why issuing a warning here would be impossible (or "wrong"). A dangerous nook in the language.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it.  As per Mat's comment is this really that much more overhead compared to doing a couple of extra IF statements?  I though operator functions were equal to the operator in terms of speed?

Comment: The overhead is just nanoseconds and in your case probably doesn't matter. See my updates for more details.